# Find StackOverflow generating code in C# using VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, c#-4.0, stack-overflow

I have solution with few projects for calculation proposes. Code after 20 minutes of work crashing by `StackOverflowException`. How to find problem? I don't have any recursion functions in code or when i have then by mistake, i don't writing this things.

With what tool i can find some recursions or other things that can produce `StackOverFlowException`? Or how to find some information that can lead me to solve problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking at the stack-trace to see where the exception is raised?

Comment: You can use `break points` in VS2010 to pin point where actually the exception is occuring.

Comment: @Dave: {Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.} I dont know from what get info about where set this breakpoints.

Comment: Don't just start your program and wait until it bombs.  You've got nothing but shrapnel to look at.  Systematically test the logical parts of your program.

Comment: Do you know about unit tests? Now might be a good time to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it in the VS debugger and look at the call stack after the exception occurs.

Comment: [External Code] - this is only one position on Call Stack, this mean to me nothing.

Comment: @Svisstack: Disable Just My Code in Debugger Options